# Gnosis Safe API issue

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have created a simple proposer/approver app and faced with some error:

```
FetchError: request to https://safe-transaction-arbitrum.safe.global//api/v1/safes/*address*/multisig-transactions/?executed=false&nonce__gte=54 failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 18.65.229.28:443
```

It happens in my cron function that executes every minute. Here is the line that throws this error:

```
const safeTxs = await this.safeApiKit.getPendingTransactions(safeWalletAddress);
```

Note that yesterday this worked absolutely fine and there were no changes to the code.
Therefore, I assume that this is a problem with the API.

Thanks :)